# How to get list of registered GlobalFilters in ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and I want do something when action decorate by some attribute. I can get attribute of action method and attribute of controller. but cant find attributes that register in `FilterConfig`.

How can find them?

My code is:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new SomeFilterOrAttribute());
}
```

and

```
public class BeforeActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var actionAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        var controllerAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true);

        // How can get list of registered global filters or attributes? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GlobalFilters` class allows to retrieve global filters collection as well as modify it

```
//requires "using System.Linq"
var globalFilters = GlobalFilters.Filters.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. But why didn't I find it myself?